# PHP creating ics invite

Tags: javascript, php, calendar, icalendar

I am using PHP to create an ICS invite for outlook. Meetings are created through a tool and then at the end you have the option to add the reminder to your calendar.

Is it possible to have everyone be added to the same invite as they add it to their calendar?  For example, I create the meeting through the tool and then it has a unique ID for the invite. Anyone who then accepts the meeting through the tool and adds the ics to their calendar, it then shows them as an attendee on the invite. Is this possible?

I see that there is a UID in the ICS file which seems to be unique. Is this the ID of the event?

Just wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the UID is the ID of the event. It should be preserved when you send updates/changes to your event.